# Hyperlink between footnote mark (left after an author's name) and footnote text

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes

I use `\thanks{}` to leave a footnote after an author's name. What I would like is that, when the reader clicks on the footnote mark, s/he be automatically taken to the associated footnote. Is that possible and, if the answer is yes, how?

Comment: Please create a minimal working example, it does make it easier. You will need the `hyperref` package for hyperlinks at least.

Comment: Okay I am adding the example.

Comment: You should use `\thanks` rather than `\footnote` in the arguments of the `\title` and `\author` macros.

Comment: Loading package `hyperref` might help as well ;-) Have a look at the documentation to learn how to use it.

Comment: The texfile is working great  when i do not add any `\thanks` or `\footnote` on the tittle or author name.. Do I need to add anything to the user package.

Comment: As stated before, you need to load/use package  `hyperref`